# The label parameter should be set so this transition can be better inspected in Animation Preview

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I follow the example code in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#updateTransition, and notice a warning as below. I tried Shift-Option-Enter, but it is not auto fixed.

I am not sure what the fix should be. Can someone advise?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning asks you for the `label` parameter:

```
updateTransition(currentState, label = "inspection label")
```